# MVC unique HTML IDs with helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

New to MVC

The model is a list of:

```
public class person
{
[Display(Name = "ID")]
public object personID{ set; get; }
[Display(Name = "Last Name")]
public object personLastName { set; get; }
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
public object personFirstName{ set; get; }
}
```

On the view:

```
@model = List<person>
foreach(person member in Model)
{
Html.LabelFor(member.personLastName)
Html.EditorFor(member.personLastName)
```

etc.

Each Label will focus on the first editor, I'm assuming due to all the IDs being the same. 
Passing the id as "fieldname + id" in each helper works, but is tedious, is there any easy way of creating ids or a more appropriate way of doing things?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't necessarily, but (among other things) the labels don't function correctly since the names and ids of all the elements created are the same for each member.

Its also a massive oversimplification, its someone else's code, and it has nested editor in nested editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to allow editing of a List of models.  I highly suggest you read [Phil Haacked - Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).  This is a great resource to get started.